# Interrupts on Arduino Due

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

Unlike any other board , every pin on Arduino due can be used as interrupt.How that's possible? What is the concept behind that?
Apart from due , are there any boards /MCUs that can do the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, it's because the microcontroller that the Due uses (AT91SAM; [datasheet PDF](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc11057.pdf)) supports it:

> Up to 103 I/O lines **with external interrupt capability** (edge or level
>   sensitivity), debouncing, glitch filtering and on-die Series Resistor
>   Termination

To the second question, yes, there are plenty of MCUs that have this same feature. For example, you can use the [Atmel parts selector](http://www.atmel.com/v2pfresults.aspx#%28actives%3a!%288238,8394,8362,8282,8431,8300,8358,8304,8378,8445,8236,8449,8474,8447,8256,8254,8286,8462,8429,8458,8466,8400,8302,8278%29,data%3a%28area%3a%27%27,category%3a%2734864%27,pm%3a!%28%28i:8238,v%3a!%280,18%29%29,%28i:8394,v%3a!%280,20%29%29,%28i:8362,v%3a!%281,30%29%29,%28i:8282,v%3a!%280,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10%29%29,%28i:8431,v%3a!%280,35%29%29,%28i:8300,v%3a!%281,9%29%29,%28i:8358,v%3a!%281,64%29%29,%28i:8392,v%3a!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8378,v%3a!n%29,%28i:8445,v%3a!%280,3,4,5,6,7,8%29%29,%28i:8236,v%3a!%280,29%29%29,%28i:8449,v%3a!%280,10%29%29,%28i:8474,v%3a!%280%29%29,%28i:8248,v%3a!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8264,v%3a!%280,5%29%29,%28i:8447,v%3a!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8256,v%3a!%281,2,3,4%29%29,%28i:8254,v%3a!%281,15%29%29,%28i:8286,v%3a!%280,3%29%29,%28i:8462,v%3a!%280,8%29%29,%28i:8429,v%3a!%281,10%29%29,%28i:8458,v%3a!%280,5%29%29,%28i:8466,v%3a!%281,2,3,4%29%29,%28i:8400,v%3a!%280,20%29%29,%28i:8302,v%3a!%280,1,2%29%29,%28i:8278,v%3a!%280,1,2%29%29,%28i:8304,v%3a!n%29%29,view%3alist%29,sc:1%29) to find MCUs whose `# of IO pins` == `# of external interrupts`.

Answer (score 0):

> are there any boards /MCUs that can do the same thing ?

All Arduinos based on the ATmega328 or ATmega168 support a pin change interrupt on every signal pin; Arduinos based on the ATmega1280 or ATmega2560 support a pin change interrupt on nearly every pin ( [Arduino: PinChangeInt](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PinChangeInt) ).

Many mid-range Microchip PIC chips (PIC16xxx) support a "Interrupt on Change" on all pins of Port B; Mark Palmer wrote [app note AN566 about it in 1997](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en011050).
John Temples mentions that PIC18xxx chips have the same feature (and [the same bug](http://www.xargs.com/pic/portb-change-bug.html)).

The Microchip PIC24 and dsPIC chips support "change notification interrupt" on many pins which as far as I can tell is the same thing. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836786/how-to-reset-the-input-pins-after-reading-their-state-in-pic24 ).

Many Texas Instruments MSP430 chips have "interrupt on state change" on most of their pins, which is another way of saying the same thing.